# Set up Git incorrectly and committed to Github

Tags: linux, git, github

I've made a typo when setting up my Git. Then used the incorrect setup to commit to my GitHub. latter,  I realized that GitHub is not recording my commits (Not showing my profile picture on the commit and of course didn't count these commits) My question is, is there a way to tell fix this issue? So GitHub knows that they were committed by me?.

Comment: Do you mean *commits*, not *comments*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub [matches](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#you-havent-added-your-local-git-commit-email-to-your-profile) commit author by email, so ensure that:

- your email is added to your github profile
- your email is set in your local [git config](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/)

If you want to change author email for exiting commits, follow [this instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).

(You can use `git commit --amend` for single commit or `git filter-branch` for multiple commits. See details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git).)